# Fully qualified domain HttpWebRequest returns 400 while short name does not

Tags: httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

When I execute this HttpWebRequest on our network

_webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(http://wdws0/cons-sandbox/weborb.aspx);

it works just fine.

When I fully qualify the url "http://woodward.com.wdws0/cons-sandbox/weborb.aspx" I get the following :

> The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Any ideas why that is ? The fully qualified version works fine entered into a browser.

Comment: Try to trace what is going on at the network layer. Use http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html to enable debug logging and see the logfile. It could be that the browser is sending the request via a proxy and that works for some reason, whereas httpwebrequest is going directly and the server does not like the request it is getting. Either way, a tracelog might indicate the problem.

Comment: My question before was not correct. I am getting a (404) not found using HttpWebRequest.GetResponse when using a fully qualified url ie. http://wdws0.woodward.com/XXXX;  while http://wdws0/XXXX works fine. This code is built on the .Net CF 3.5. The same request using a browser works fine either way the url is formed. I'm not sure how to trace the traffic using the emulator. Any suggestions?

Comment: are you running this on a device? I thought you were doing it on the desktop?

Comment: can you try to repro it on your desktop? then use the link I gave to generate a logfile and we can see what is happening.

Comment: When I run from a device I get a 404 not found. When I run from the desktop emulator I am now getting can't connect to server. I'm being rejected at the server. I appreciate your help. I think I'm close to getting the issue tracked down. There seems to be some disparity in our internal network configuration between US locations and international sites.

Comment: can your emulator connect to any internet or intranet site at all?

Comment: Yes it connects just fine on my intranet as long as I don't fully qualify the url.

Comment: Yes it connects just fine on my intranet as long as I don't fully qualify the url. If I send http://wdws0/therest... I have no issue from my emulator or device. When I send http://wdws0.woodward.com/therest... I then either see a (400) Bad request, (and I have seen the inner exception return "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"), or I get a (404) Not found error.

Comment: is it possible that a fully qualified url is causing the request to go via a proxy, and that is failing? Only getting a full debug log will point you to the root cause.

Comment: feroze- Thank you for your help. I was able to get this figured out I think. It is a proxy issue. I installed a logging tool on my device and looked at the network traffic. I saw that a fully qualified url was hitting our proxy server. I tried the same request with the header.proxy set to null. Then I was seeng a 302 Found error and more problems. I did some more research on the 302 and found a clue that said to make sure my url had a trailing slash. Sure enough mine did not. After addin that and setting header proxy = null I was able to connect. Thanks for heading me don the road.